# Auto-export TikZ images (previously expand (print) contents of a TikZ style)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-external

**EDIT:** The external library is great but I'd like to add I figured out how to print the contents of a style (although not fully expanded, so if it contains other styles, they will not be). A style is stored in a `.@cmd` subkey, in the same place as the code of the key. So a `\pgfkeys{/key/.code=<code>}` directive puts `<code>` directly into `/key/.@cmd`, whereas the `/.style` directive wraps it in `/pgfkeysalso{<style>}`. (So `/.code` and `/.style` either append to or override each other.):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\mean#1{\texttt{\string#1: \meaning#1}\par}

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{my style/.style={draw=red}}
\pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/my style/.@cmd}{\mystyle}
\mean\mystyle

% strip \pgfkeysalso prefix, only works if style hasn't been prepended or appended to
\def\getstyle\pgfkeysalso #1\@nil{\def\mystyle{#1}}
\expandafter\getstyle\mystyle\pgfeov\@nil
\mean\mystyle
\end{document}
```

---

I have a macro which does some processing based on its argument (it set some length registers and TikZ styles) and then draws a simple TikZ picture using those lengths and styles. I need a way of writing the expanded contents of the picture to a file, so it can be `\input` during subsequent compilations, bypassing all the processing overhead. I know how to expand the length registers and how to `\write` the TikZ commands without expansion, but I don't know how to print the contents of the styles: so if during the processing I have executed `\tikzset{my style/.style={draw=red}}`, I want to be able to substitute all occurrences of my style with `draw=red`, or whatever its content, during writing. I don't know if this is possible, or it would involve setting the style (which it would be anyway) and manually getting the values of all relevant keys using `\pgfkeysvalueof`. I know I can instead write the `\tikzset` command verbatim, so the styles are set and used within the newly created file, but I was wondering if there's a better way. Here is a **very** simplified version of what my package does:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\gtikzset#1{
  \begingroup%
  \globaldefs=1\relax%
  \tikzset{#1}%
  \endgroup%
}

% do some preprocessing here to compute styles; as far as MWE is concerned,
% let's just set styles 0--100 to be red
\foreach \n in {0,...,100}{\gtikzset{anyon\n/.style={red}}}

\newcount\childn
% the child operation seems to start a new group, so not using \global to
% advance the childn counter results it being equal to the current
% depth, #1
\def\DrawChildren#1#2{%
  % #1: current depth, #2: total depth
  \ifnumless{#1}{#2}{%
    % right
    child[anyon\the\childn] {%
      node {}%
      \pgfextra{\global\advance\childn by 1\relax}%
      \DrawChildren{#1+1}{#2} }%
    % left
    child[anyon\the\childn] {%
      node {}%
      \pgfextra{\global\advance\childn by 1\relax}%
      \DrawChildren{#1+1}{#2} }%
  }{}%
}

\def\DrawTree#1{%
  % #1: tree depth
  \childn=1\relax%
  % do more processing here, compute lengths, use them to clip the image
  % \clip...
  \node [anyon0] {} child { node {} \DrawChildren{0}{#1} };%
}

\begin{document}
\tikz\DrawTree{3};
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the overhead of `tikzset`?

Comment: @percusse I guess it's insignificant, I think it's the calculations needed to determine the styles that slow it down.

Comment: Also pretty insignificant. It's the drawing part that takes time.

Comment: Yes, but the processing overhead is still about a third of the time. I checked how long it takes me to draw 3 (note I have tens, even more, of those trees in a single document) such 6-level trees at different stages:

before setting default styles:  0.17s
after setting default styles:   0.37s
after setting user styles:   0.51s
after additional processing (lengths): 0.53s
after drawing:     1.72s

possibly it would be better to write a standalone file that calls the macro to draw the tree, then compile this into pdf (call it with \write18) and include the pdf in the document...

Comment: That's pretty normal for trees no? I don't think it will be different when you print them out. You might actually do some protocolling. Check the relevant part of the manual if you really need that speed benefit.

Comment: What about [`\tikzexternalize`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf#section.50)?  We can't  really help you without seeing a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: percusse, @Henri Menke, thank you both for your suggestions, I didn't know about either of those features (haven't made it that far into the pgf manual). The protocol system sounds like it may work but the external library is probably the way to go. I'm not sure what a minimal example would include, the actual code is very long (although not super technical). I have added what I think may be of help to the OP nevertheless.

Comment: @Henri Menke, indeed the external library is amazingly powerful it did exactly what I need! I can include support in my macro for automatically naming each figure (external/figure name, I mean) based on its content (the arguments given to the macro), so that moving them around the document, or using it more than once will not cause it to be rebuild. I also love the list and make mode. I'm already using a Makefile for this project and this integrates perfectly, allowing me to compile the pictures in parallel. If you write an answer, I can accept it; otherwise I'll edit my OP. Thanks!

Comment: Although the `external` library seems the obvious choice here, for future reference, take a look at the `standalone` class if you're not done so already. It might be useful in cases where externalisation fails, though I'm not certain about this.

Comment: Also, it really looks as if Forest would be helpful here.

Comment: @cfr I am familiar with standalone, in fact I am using it for my project already. And this is what I originally had in mind: writing the code for each tree in a standalone .tex file, but I still don't know what the best way would be: a) find a way to expand the contents of the style or b) write the \tikzset commands to the file. As for forest, I had a look at it when you recommended it to me way back, but I wanted to create an interface specific to my purpose (with a very specific syntax for specifying the tree), and it is written already anyway.

Comment: I didn't mean you should use `standalone` for this if the externalisation works. But if it fails, `standalone` can do something similar i.e. compile the code to an image and then include the image, to save recompiling pictures when they haven't changed. But I would, in that case, create the `standalone` `.tex` manually to avoid having the code written to file each time. Given your current setup, that's obviously less convenient. But if some images can't be externalised, it might be an attractive second line to pursue for those. As for Forest, I don't suggest rewriting the current code.

Comment: @cfr Sorry, I didn't make myself clear. I know I shouldn't use standalone when tikz's external library works, I meant I wanted to use standalone before I knew about this library. And my idea was to 1) check if the <unique autogenerated name>.pdf exists and include it, otherwise 2) check if <unique...>.tex exists, compile it (with \write18) and include the .pdf; otherwise 3) compute the styles, write the <unique...>.tex file and do step 2). All of this was to avoid having to manually write those files and include their names in the main document.

Comment: So none of the trees will change after they are first compiled or written?

Comment: @cfr It is unlikely that they do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Henri Menke's suggestions was exactly what I needed: TikZ has an external library, which automatically exports any tikzpicture into a pdf file and is highly customizable (chapter 50 of pgf manual).

To start using it all one needs is:

```
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
```

To enable/disable externalization of pictures until the end of the current group (or until the next disable/enable command): `\tikzexternalenable` or `\tikzexternaldisable`. To skip just the next figure: `\tikzset{external/export next=false}`

By default it names files by `\jobname-figure<n>` where `<n>` starts at 0, this can be changed with either `\tikzsetfigurename{<name>}` or `\tikzset{external/figure name=<name>}`. This sets the basename for all figures (it is local to a group though) and each figure gets a number at the end. To set the full basename of the next picture, use `\tikzsetnextfilename{<file name>}`. One can set a global prefix, such as a directory path, that will be applied to each image using `\tikzsetexternalprefix{<prefix>}` or `\tikzset{external/prefix={<prefix>}}`. This prefix is applied even to images whose filename is specifically set. One can set a suffix as well using `\tikzappendtofigurename{<suffix>}`.

By default it uses a hash of the contents of the tikzpicture environment to figure out if the picture has changed. This won't work if the picture uses externally defined macros and they change, but one can always force a rebuild of the next figure using `\tikzset{external/remake next=true}` or globally for all figures using `\tikzset{external/force remake=true}`. There are other up-to-date-check modes to choose from: `\tikzset{external/up to date check={<mode>}}`, where `<mode>` can be one of `md5` (default), `diff` (similar to md5) or `simple` (to merely check if file with this name exists). When using simple, if the order of figures is changed, this won't be reflected in the main document until the external figures are rebuilt (manually or by forcing TikZ). Additionally, one can set a dependency for a particular figure using `\tikzpicturedependsonfile{<file name>}`, so that if `<file name>` changes the picture will be rebuilt.

There are several modes which determine how (and if) exported images are compiled: `\tikzset{external/mode={<mode>}}`. The modes are:

- `convert with system call`: call a system command (using \write18) to make each image in succession.
- `only graphics`: assume all exported images have been compiled already and only include them (it's an error if file doesn't exist)
- `graphics if exists`: same as above, but silently skip those for which a binary file cannot be found
- `no graphics`: do not check external graphics at all, always typesetting pictures
- `list only`: generate `\jobname.figlist` (a line-separated file of all images to be exported); insert a replacement text for each picture in the main document
- `list and make`: in addition to generating `\jobname.figlist`, write `\jobname.makefile`, which can be used with make to do parallel compilation (when building with make or manually, also `\ref`'s inside the pictures are resolved, which is not the case in `convert with system call` mode); also, include any images which are already compiled.

The command called when using the `convert with system call` mode can be set. By default it determines the pdf driver used for the main file and adds some options. So for (pdf|lua|xe)latex, the system call would be:

```
(pdf|lua|xe)latex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"
```

where `\image` holds the full image filename (generated from figure name and any global prefixes/suffixes) and `\tikzexternalcheckshellescape` is non-empty only if `-shell-escape` has been allowed for the main document. The actual parameter that it holds (by default `-shell-escape`) can be set with `\tikzset{external/shell escape={<cmdline arg>}}`

Inside the main document code may be conditionally executed based on whether in this compilation run only the exported image is being generated, or the full document is typeset: `\tikzifexternalizing{<true code>}{<false code>}`.

There are also various ways to optimize the exported figures by ignoring certain macro calls inside them, see the manual for more.

With that said, I can include support in my macro for automatically naming each figure based on its content, so that moving them around the document, or using it more than once will not cause it to be rebuilt. I also love the list and make mode, since I'm already using a Makefile for this project and this integrates perfectly, allowing me to compile the pictures in parallel. A MWE would be:

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[
  prefix=img/, % needs to exist
  figure name=tikz_external_test_,
  mode=list and make,
  figure list=true,
]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
  \draw (0,0) circle[radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

`Makefile`:

```
.PHONY: clean fullclean
.DEFAULT: main

# removed in 'clean' and 'fullclean'
tmp_files := $(wildcard $(addprefix main.,aux auxlock log \
    out figlist makefile))
# removed in 'fullclean' only
out_files := $(wildcard main.pdf img/*)

define compile =
       pdflatex $(1)
       $(MAKE) -f $(1).makefile # can add -j<N> for parallel compilation
       pdflatex $(1)
endef

main: main.pdf

%.pdf: %.tex
    $(call compile,$*)

clean:
ifneq ($(tmp_files),)
    rm $(tmp_files)
endif

fullclean:
ifneq ($(strip $(tmp_files) $(out_files)),)
    rm $(tmp_files) $(out_files)
endif
```